# My XCode workspace doesn't remember added projects when restarted

Tags: xcode, macos, project

I've added Google's GTL project to my project's workspace. It works fine, but every time I open XCode it disappears and I have to add it again. Why can't it remember this project? Is there a cache file or derived data I need to delete and rebuild?

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that you are opening the .xcworkspace, not the .xcodeproj.

When you add the extra project to create a workspace the first time, XCode asks you to save a .xcworkspace file. This is is the file you have to open.

Comment: I'm definitely opening the xcworkspace file. Do workspace files have a config file or plist where they keep a record of all projects that have been added? Could mine have been corrupted or set to read-only?

Comment: Yes, the .xcworkspace is a directory. Inside it is the config file.